# HTACCESS index inside folder issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku, directory, port

I having a strange situation with an index.html inside a folder in my Heroku php app.
My [website](http://comunidadget.com/) have two versions: Spanish ane English. The english one is just inside a folder named **en/**

Here's the problem: **I can't access comunidadget.com/en/index.html** on my website. After I do this it goes to comunidadget.com:39906 I have no freaking idea why. And if I just type comunidadget.com/en it says it doesn't find the file.

I have an htaccess in the en folder to allow rewrite and access to that folder, in fact if your go to another page inside it, everything goes fine. Example [Contact](http://comunidadget.com/en/contact)

Anyway, this is started happening a few days ago and it's driving me NUTS.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can access your site: comunidadget.com/en/index.html

--> maybe the simple solution is deleting your Browsercache
--> I had similar problems a few days ago

For switching to english supply the filename in your link (ENGLISH) comunidadget.com/en/index.html (or make a htaccess in the en/folder)